# Using a circuit to make a magnetic balance to weigh objects

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I understand that this is a homework question, but I am learning about magnetic fields and things like that and this certainly wasn't covered in the material, so my question is more about the actual CONCEPT of using a circuit to make a magnetic balance to weigh objects. Nothing in this problem really explains ..what exactly is making us be able to "weigh" ANYTHING. I understand that when the battery is turned on, a current will go through the circuit, and [**correct me if I'm wrong**] when it is passing through the bar holding the mass, it will create a force that should be either pointing up or down (because the force will be perpendicular to the plane formed by the field and the direction of the moving charged mass). This is the actual problem statement:

*The circuit shown in the figure is used to make a magnetic balance to weigh objects. The mass m to be measured is hung from the center of the bar, that is in a uniform magnetic field of 1.50 T, directed into the plane of the figure. The battery voltage can be adjusted to vary the current in the circuit. The horizontal bar is 60.0 cm long and is made of extremely light-weight material. It is connected to the battery by thin vertical wires that can support no appreciable tension; all the weight of the suspended mass m is supported by the magnetic force on the bar. A resistor with R = 5.00 Ω is in series with the bar; the resistance of the rest of the circuit is much less than this*

[image]

and the question is: Which point, a or b, should be the positive terminal of the battery?

The correct answer is a, meaning using the right hand rule) that there will be an upward force on the bar. I don't really understand what this means in terms of "weighing" the mass at all, or how it helps in any way, and I was hoping somebody could clear this up.

Comment: What other force acts on the mass?

Comment: @DevinCrossman The force of gravity

Comment: You can determine the weight of the mass by setting the magnetic force equal to the force of gravity

Answer (score 1):

You must put a battery with the positive terminal on (a) that has such potential difference that gives you a high enough current thay in its turn gives you a force equal but opposite of the gravitational force of the mass.In that way, you can determine the mass of the object.
The magnetic force will pull upwards while the gravitational one will pull downwards, so you must make them equal in order to find the mass the easiest way.